# PHP: Implement edit and delete buttons for UI table

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a sort of custom Administrative UI.

I have implemented the php code that inserts and reads records from the DB table.

The records are visualized in a table in the UI in the below pattern:

test title

Added: 2011-12-29 17:34:35

test2

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

test title

Added: 2011-12-29 17:34:35  tests

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

test title2
Added: 2011-12-29 17:34:35  test22

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I have the following structure for my database table:

TABLE news (
  guid  ,
  lang  ,
  title  ,
  content ,
  date,
  PRIMARY KEY  (guid, lang)
)

guid is generated with php com_create_guid () function.

How can I implement buttons Edit and Delete beside each item?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- you can make a form with hidden inputs that contain record id and buttons with different names. For each record:

> ```
> <form action="action.php" method="POST">
>    <input type="hidden" name="record_id" value="12">
>    <input type="submit" value="Edit" name="doedit">
>    <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="dodelete">
> </form>
> ```

In action.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['doedit'])){do smth.}
if (isset($_POST['dodelete'])){do smth.}
```

- you can make links instead giving each different url containing action and record id as GET parameters.
  Suppose you have a file action.php. For record number 12 the "edit" link will go to "action.php?do=edit&record=12", the "delete" link will go to "action.php?do=delete&record=12".
  In action.php:

  > $do=$_GET['do'];  //you should add some validation of $_GET
  >   $rec=$_GET['record'];   if ($do=='edit'){do smth.}   if
  >   ($do=='delete'){do smth.}

Comment: Thanks for your answer, could you please elaborate a little bit on each option? I am failry new to web development.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! I have implemented the first option. For record_id i am passing the unique guid for each record from the db table. Now I am wondering how to actually edit the text of each record... After the "Edit" button is pressed how I can make the text in each record editable?

Comment: You can output a form with editable textfield and the record as the text inside in the action.php. you can change the div with the record to textfield using javascript. I think there are plenty other options

Comment: I have actually implemented it a bit differently - using radio buttons, as they support the same name but different values, and allow the editing of one single record at a time. On $_POST I read only the value of the selected radio button, and after that handle the database query based on this id. I also implemented everything in one file where the action = "" to avoid passing parameters to another php file. WORKS. Thanks for the basic idea! Was of great help!